# How can I copy an element from website to variable /clipboard?

Tags: javascript, java, html

How can I copy an element from website to var/clipboard?
for example, if I want to copy this article title from this website to variable or to my clipboard (Donald Trump posts video clip of him 'beating' CNN in wrestling) [link](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-40474118)
I mean to create a code in java that will work on any bbc website and will give me the article title. In the case I have described above it should be (Donald Trump posts video clip...)

I'm a beginner in developing code and I'll be glad if you help me to do this simple code and give me tips how can I learn this topic and how it called in the developing world.

Best regards. :)

Comment: You're looking for JSoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use JSoup. Then your code should look something like this:

If you wanna fetch info from website title (because page title = page header, as I could see):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
String title = doc.title();
```

If you wanna fetch info directly from their h2 element for titles:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
Elements news = doc.getElementsByClass("story-body__h1");
String whatYouNeed = news.text();
```

Edit: Example for your page would be:

```
String link = "http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-40474118";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
String title = doc.title();
```